# How to use the OS default theme as my app's theme?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to use the user's Windows 10 Mobile theme (dark or light) automatically in my app so my app is in line with the chose theme on the OS. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `RequestedTheme="Light"` attribute from your App.xaml file. If you do not set a `RequestedTheme`, then it will use the system theme by default.

Comment: @ÂhmêdBôgâ are you using any custom themes?

Comment: @Âhmêd Bôgâ What is the error? During compile rime or run time? What is your current system theme?

Comment: It's better.Not set is use the system but when my app run,the system be set ,my app will change?

Comment: @ÂhmêdBôgâ The styles in your app will update automatically when the user changes their system theme provided you are using the `ThemeResource` markup extension in your XAML. If you need more help with theming, you should create another question.

Comment: when I remove the RequestedTheme="Light" attribute from your App.xaml file. that error happen, 

1-Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  An attribute name is missing. Muhammed C:\Users\ahmed\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MuhammedSOL\Muhammed\App.xaml

2-Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The token "</" is unexpected. Muhammed C:\Users\ahmed\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MuhammedSOL\Muhammed\App.xaml

and others error :(

Comment: @ÂhmêdBôgâ You should literally *only* remove the `RequestedTheme="Light"` characters and nothing else. You didn't delete the `>` character after it, did you? I think you just have a syntax error.

Comment: i don't remove anything, thats happen with itself

Comment: Can you edit your question with a snippet of your App.xaml file if possible? I can't help you any more unless I can see your problematic XAML code.

Comment: https://s15.postimg.org/fxjuoscln/image.png

in this link screenshot when i delete  RequestedTheme="Light"

Comment: Yes, I explained above that the cause was probably that you removed the `>` character. I said to remove `RequestedTheme="Light"`, not `RequestedTheme="Light">`. Put a `>` on the end of line 5.